# Aggregate multiplicate function

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

I have a table of the following:

```
1    X    10
2    X    30
3    Y    5
4    Y    2
...etc
```

I need to turn it into:

```
X    300   //(10 * 30)
Y    10    //(5 * 2)
```

so I'm in fact looking for a kind of a multiplication function that I could use like sum, avg and stuff... does this exist guys?

for instance:

```
select field2, **multiply**(field3)
from t
group by field2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ideally, Access SQL would have a `PRODUCT` aggregate function available, but it doesn't. We can however simulate it by remembering what we learned about logarithms at school (or not...), and remembering that the anti-log of the sum of logs is equal to the product:

```
SELECT field2, EXP(Sum(LOG(Field3))) AS ProductOfField3
FROM t
GROUP BY Field2
```

Note that whereas a true `PRODUCT` function would simply return `0` for a group if there are any zero values, this solution will **fail** if there are any zero values, so watch out for that. Also, this approach won't work if there are any negative values.

To deal with zeroes we could do this:

```
SELECT
    field2, 
    EXP(Sum(LOG(IIf(Field3 = 0, 1, Field3)))) AS ProductOfField3,
    MIN(ABS(Field3)) AS MinOfAbsField3
FROM t
GROUP BY Field2
```

and then disregard the `ProductOfField3` value for any row where `MinOfAbsField3` is zero (as this indicates a group containing a zero, thus the 'true' product should be `0`)

To deal with negative values we could further do this:

```
SELECT
    field2, 
    EXP(Sum(LOG(IIf(Field3 = 0, 1, ABS(Field3))))) AS ProductOfField3,
    MIN(ABS(Field3)) AS MinOfAbsField3,
    SUM(IIf(Field3 < 0, 1, 0)) AS SumOfNegativeIndicator
FROM t
GROUP BY Field2
```

and interpret the results with these rules:

- If `MinOfAbsField3` is zero, disregard `ProductOfField3` for that row - the product is zero
- Otherwise, the required answer for a given row is `ProductOfField3`, **negated** if `SumOfNegativeIndicator` is odd in that row

Comment: Thanks AakashM. I tried it this way but it didn't work, it keeps saying "Invalid procedure call" and I couldn't spot where the error is coming from exactly. I'm though sure it's not coming from the rest of my query, seems access doesn't like EXP(Sum(LOG([X]))) or whatever. I ended up using a crosstable since I do only have at most 3 columns to multiplicate, but i'll keep this noted for future needs.

Comment: @CoolStraw that is the error you will get if any of the values are zero (or negative). I will update to indicate one way to deal with this situation

Comment: +1. Another awkward case is if you are not grouping but computing the product of a whole table or result set that is empty. The product should be 1.

Comment: I'm wondering why `EXP(Sum(LOG(Nz(Field3,0))))` wouldn't take care of the Null problem?

Comment: Nz(Field3, 1) would solve the problem. the natural logarithm of zero doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

## You can define following two functions:

```
Public Function ResetProd() As Boolean
    Call Prod(Null)
    ResetProd = True
End Function

Public Function Prod(nNumber As Variant) As Double
    Static nPrevNumber As Double
    If IsNull(nNumber) Then
        nPrevNumber = 1
    Else
        nPrevNumber = nPrevNumber * nNumber
    End If
    Prod = nPrevNumber
End Function
```

...and use them as follows:

```
SELECT PROD(_column_for_wich_you_want_product_) FROM _your_table_
WHERE RESETPROD()
```

Comment: This looks nice in theory, but have you actually tried it? It doesn't really work for me (some rows are multiplied more than once), and mainly: it doesn't aggregate. And you can't use GROUP BY.