# How to multiply the values in a column of table in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to multiply the values in ID column of mytable :

```
ID
1
2
3
4
```

I am using the SQL query as below:

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(ID))) as result 
from dbo.mytable with (nolock)
```

Any other ways to calculate the multiplication of ID values, Please share.

Comment: Specify your expected result

Comment: @karthikaseenivas You want the product of all the IDs?

Comment: may be you are looking for this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409884/how-to-find-running-multiplication

Comment: What's wrong with the method you have?  There's not a built-in multiplication aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

You can do It simply by declaring an variable

```
DECLARE @MulVal INT SELECT @MulVal = Id * COALESCE(@MulVal, 1) FROM #Tbl SELECT @MulVal
```