# How can I multiply numbers(data) in one column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I multiply all numbers in one column?

for example:

```
Status(finished or not finished)
            1
            1
            1
            1
            0
```

I know how to use sum.

```
sum(Status)=4
```

I need some thing like sum for multiply

```
mul(status)=0
```

do we have something like `mul(status)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416169/mutiplication-aggregate-operator-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a multiply aggregate function.  However, in the case of a column containing only zeroes and ones the product will be one only if every value be one, otherwise it will be zero:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUM(status) = COUNT(status) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS product
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN SUM(status) = COUNT(status) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS product
```

Comment: Answers in SO should contain some text explaining why it is the answer in addition to corrected code.