# multiply records acrross a rows - pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I ve got simple table

```
ID  VALUE
-------------
1    3
2    5
3    6
```

How can i multiply all this records(value) and group in one column in ORACLE? Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416169/mutiplication-aggregate-operator-in-sql#5416205

Comment: @lad2025 you are my hero! Thank you. It s solved!

Comment: I am glad I can help you :)