# TSQL window function to calculate interest

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate interest using window functions on SQL Server 2022

```
with t as 
(
    select * 
    from 
        (values
            ('2000-1-1',100,0.1),
            ('2000-1-2',100,0.1),
            ('2000-1-3',100,0.1),
            ('2000-1-4',100,0.1),
            ('2000-1-5',100,0.1),
            ('2000-1-6',100,0.1)
        ) as t(date, amount, perc)
)
select 
    *, 
    perc * sum(amount) over (order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) / 365 interest,
    sum(amount) over (order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) +
        perc * sum(amount) over (order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) / 365
from 
    t
```

[image]

Can someone point me to a problem why interest calculated isn't being cummulated f.e. I expect balance to be 300.08 on 3rd while it is 300.05 (interest from 2nd isn't taken into account)

Comment: It is cumulative, what you want is *recursive*.

Comment: you can't do this kind of stuff with just window functions, because they don't allow you to access previously *calculated* value

Comment: To elaborate, the value of `balance` is being calculated as `(100 + 100 + 100) + ((0.1 * (100+100)) / 365) = 300 + ((0.1 * 200) / 365) = 300 + (20 / 365) = 300 + 0.05479 = 3.05479`

Comment: What *you* want is `100 + (100 + ((0.1*100)/365)) + (100 + ((0.1*200.027397)/365))` where `200.027397` is the value of `100 + (100 + ((0.1*100)/365))`

Comment: Aside... the date values you're specifying there are just strings. If you want to do some calculations with them when using a values constructor like that you may wish to use ODBC date literals to avoid casting, e.g. `{d'2000-01-06'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this isn't cumulative aggregation it's *recursive* aggregation. Effectively your expression wants to read something like:
Amount + PriorBalance + (Interest + (Percentage * PriorBalance) / 365)

To achieve this, you're doing to need to use a recursive CTE, as a cumulative `SUM` (or any of the windowed aggregated) cannot access the prior rows calculated value.

Therefore this appears to be the solution you need:

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT date,
           amount,
           perc,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) AS I
    FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'20000101'),100,0.1),
                (CONVERT(date,'20000102'),100,0.1),
                (CONVERT(date,'20000103'),100,0.1),
                (CONVERT(date,'20000104'),100,0.1),
                (CONVERT(date,'20000105'),100,0.1),
                (CONVERT(date,'20000106'),100,0.1)) as t(date,amount,perc)),
rCTE AS (
    SELECT date,
           amount,
           perc,
           I,
           CONVERT(numeric(7,6),0.000000) AS interest,
           CONVERT(numeric(12,6),0.000000) AS balance
    FROM t
    WHERE I = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.date,
           t.amount,
           t.perc,
           t.I,
           CONVERT(numeric(7,6),r.interest + ((t.perc * r.amount)/365)) AS interest,
           CONVERT(numeric(12,6),t.amount + r.balance + (r.interest + ((t.perc * r.amount)/365))) AS balance
    FROM t t
         JOIN rCTE r ON r.I = t.I -1
)
SELECT date,
       amount,
       perc,
       interest,
       balance
FROM rCTE;
GO
```

Comment: I believe you can do recursive multiplication using `EXP(SUM(LOG(someValue)) OVER (ORDER BY...))` but can't get my head round how to do it with a yearly interest split by day. Something like https://dbfiddle.uk/c8GIuHA1

Comment: Not a method I'm familiar with, @Charlieface , but if I recall I'll have a go tomorrow.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5416205/14868997

Comment: I would fix it slightly: first day's balance is equal to its amount and day's interest as "previous day balance * rate"

Comment: Recursive version does not work for longer periods (The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.)

Comment: With EXP(SUM(LOG()) OVER()) - how to calculate value of interest (as rate * previous day balance)? I was trying EXP(SUM(LOG(0 + perc / 365)) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING)) * SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS between UNBOUNDED preceding and 1 PRECEDING) but it gives me strange results

Comment: You'll need to increase the max recursion in your `OPTION` clause, @Kodak . As your sample data only contained 6 rows, I didn't add it.

Comment: recursion looks like an overkill to me as I need to run it on two years period; EXP SUM LOG would be fine if I could calculate value of interest...