# Compounded yearly return calculation using monthly returns in MySQL

Tags: sql, return, mysql-workbench

Hope you can help me as i am stuck.

I have a query with 4 columns: id, name, date and monthly return.

I want to calculate the year to date compounded return per id using the Formula:

> `(1+return1)*(1+return2)…-1.`

My data looks like this although it is an example:

| ID | Name | Date | Monthly Return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | 31/03/2023 | -0.02 |
| 1 | Name1 | 30/04/2023 | 0.05 |
| 1 | Name1 | 31/05/2023 | 0.06 |
| 1 | Name1 | 30/06/2023 | 0.01 |
| 2 | Name2 | 31/03/2023 | -0.01 |
| 2 | Name2 | 30/04/2023 | 0.01 |
| 2 | Name2 | 31/05/2023 | 0.05 |
| 3 | Name3 | 31/03/2023 | 0.05 |
| 3 | Name3 | 30/04/2023 | 0.05 |

I keep getting only the sum and not the compound effect when i do the query. Writing this from my phone - but if anyone want the code i Can upload it in a comment.

I am using MySQL and working in workbench 8.0.33

Hope you can help me.

Tried implementing the formula and grouping on ID but i only get the sum of the monthy returns per ID.

Comment: Probably you need this: [Multiplication aggregate operator in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416169/multiplication-aggregate-operator-in-sql), in your case: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Iz3i8L9x).

Comment: Interesting Ponder. I will try an use that and revert back - Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ponder - that worked. how do i give you credit?

Comment: No need, your question is a duplicate, I remembered that linked solution.