# Oracle SQL - aggregate multplication

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the data in the following way:

```
ITEM     PERCENTAGE
MOBILE | 2
MOBILE | 5
TABLET | 5
TABLET | 3
```

I want to apply the percentages (eg 2 and 5 for item: MOBILE) as

`(1-PERCENTAGE_1%) * (1-PERCENTAGE_2%)`  --- order does not matter

the final result as

```
ITEM     PERCENTAGE
MOBILE | 0.931
TABLET | 0.9215
```

Comment: Does this question help you answer yours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416169/multiplication-aggregate-operator-in-sql

Comment: Is it always two rows per item or can there be more? With two rows this is super-simple: `select item, (100 - min(percentage)) * (100 - max(percentage)) / 10000 from mytable group by item`. With more rows you might need a recursive query instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `ln` and `exp` functions to convert multiplication into addition and vice versa. But it adds some rounding error that may be significant if number of multipliers is large or their values are too sparse.

```
select
  item,
  round(exp(sum(ln(1 - PERCENTAGE/100))), 5) as mult
from sample
group by item
```

Or use [`model` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-modeling-data-warehouses.html) to perform row-by-row iteration without approximation that arise when `ln/exp` are used.

```
with calc as (
  select *
  from sample
  model
    partition by (item)
    dimension by (row_number() over(partition by item order by null) as dim)
    measures (PERCENTAGE as mult, 0 as last_row)
    rules update (
      mult[any] order by dim = coalesce(mult[cv() - 1], 1)*(1 - mult[cv()]/100),
      /*Last row indicator that will contain aggregated value*/
      last_row[any] = decode(last_row[cv()+1], null, 1, 0)
    )
)
select
  item,
  mult
from calc
where last_row = 1
```

Or define local PL/SQL function that will iterate over collection of multipliers and perform multiplication. Then apply it to the result of `collect` aggregate function. Oracle has `sys.ODCINumberList` predefined type for `table of number`.

```
with function f_mult(nums sys.odcinumberlist)
  return number
as
  pragma udf;
  mult number := 1;
begin
  for i in 1..nums.count() loop
    mult := mult * (1 - nums(i)/100);
  end loop;
  return mult;
end;

select
  item,
  f_mult(cast(collect(PERCENTAGE) as sys.odcinumberlist)) as agg
from sample
group by item
```

For your sample data:

```
create table sample(ITEM, PERCENTAGE) as
select 'MOBILE', 2 from dual union all
select 'MOBILE', 5 from dual union all
select 'TABLET', 5 from dual union all
select 'TABLET', 3 from dual
```

all the above queries return the same result:

| ITEM | AGG |
| --- | --- |
| MOBILE | .931 |
| TABLET | .9215 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GZzH6bek)

Answer (score 0):

As items come in pairs, one option is to use `lead` analytic function and do the calculation of two values:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (item, percentage) as
  2    (select 'mobile', 2 from dual union all
  3     select 'mobile', 5 from dual union all
  4     select 'tablet', 5 from dual union all
  5     select 'tablet', 3 from dual
  6    ),
```

Query:

```
  7  temp as
  8    (select item,
  9            percentage / 100 pct,
 10            lead(percentage/100) over (partition by item order by null) pct2
 11     from test
 12    )
 13  select item,
 14         (1 - pct) * (1 - pct2) percentage
 15  from temp
 16  where pct2 is not null;

ITEM   PERCENTAGE
------ ----------
mobile       ,931
tablet      ,9215

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way using the analytic functions `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` :

```
with cte as (
  select ITEM, ( 1 - FIRST_VALUE(percentage) over (partition by item)/100) 
             * ( 1 - LAST_VALUE(percentage) over (partition by item)/100) as PERCENTAGE,
         row_number() over (partition by item order by null) as rn
  from mytable
)
select ITEM, PERCENTAGE
from cte
where rn = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/YXW7Vm8t)