# vba - get final product price when more than one discount are applied

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm new to access and totally hopeless with recordsets, so if you take the time to answer my question, please be so nice to include some brief explanation, so that I can get the hang of it.

I have 2 tables.

1) **tblProducts** with field Headers: ProductID - Product_Name - Product_Price

2) **tblProd_Disc** with field Headers: ProductID  - Discount (where each product is associated with more than 1 discount)

Goal: get the final price of each product after each of the discounts have been successively applied, eg. if product 1's price is 100 and the discounts are 10% and 15%, then final price should read 76.5.

I guess I should put this in a function that uses ProductID as parameter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounded like something that **really** should be solvable with SQL. But it isn't trivial - basically you need a **multiplication** aggregate of all discounts per product.

With lots of help from [Aggregate multiplicate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218375/aggregate-multiplicate-function) :

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Product_Name, p.Product_Price * d.Product_Discount AS Discounted_Price
FROM tblProducts p 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ProductID, EXP(SUM(LOG(1-[Discount]))) AS Product_Discount
    FROM tblProd_Disc
    GROUP BY ProductID
) d
ON p.ProductID = d.ProductID
```

But this doesn't work if a product has no discounts at all.
I tried various combinations of `Nz()` or `IIf()` to get `1` as `d.Product_Discount`, but it always returned `#Error` for this product.

As a workaround you can use a UNION query, adding those products with unmodified price.

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Product_Name, p.Product_Price * d.Product_Discount AS Discounted_Price
FROM tblProducts p 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ProductID, EXP(SUM(LOG(1-[Discount]))) AS Product_Discount
    FROM tblProd_Disc
    GROUP BY ProductID
) d
ON p.ProductID = d.ProductID

UNION

SELECT p.ProductID, p.Product_Name, p.Product_Price 
FROM tblProducts p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM tblProd_Disc d WHERE d.ProductID = p.ProductID)
```

---

My sample data:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| ProductID | Product_Name | Product_Price |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|         1 | stuff        | 100,00 €      |
|         2 | no discount  | 100,00 €      |
|         3 | one          | 100,00 €      |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+

+--------+-----------+----------+
| DiscID | ProductID | Discount |
+--------+-----------+----------+
|      1 |         1 | 10,00%   |
|      2 |         1 | 15,00%   |
|      3 |         3 | 20,00%   |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Result:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| ProductID | Product_Name | Discounted_Price |
+-----------+--------------+------------------+
|         1 | stuff        |             76,5 |
|         2 | no discount  |              100 |
|         3 | one          |               80 |
+-----------+--------------+------------------+
```

Comment: wow! I don't how the exp(log... thing works but it works!!!!!! Thank you.